# How do I find the rank position of a particular column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table called `bank`. I want to find what rank position a particular `customer_number`. For example `my_id = 5` has a rank position of `1` because he is the richest. Then `my_id = 4` would be rank `2`

```
my_id | balance | customer_number
----------------|------------------
1     | 5       | 345345345
2     | 1       | 435456
3     | 45      | 345345
4     | 81      | 43543535
5     | 95      | 4566876
6     | 45      | 324624121
```

Where `my_id = 6`, would have rank of `3`. And `my_id = 3` would also have the rank of `3` because they are duplicates. Then rank of `4` would be given to `my_id = 1`.

I also want to select the `balance` and `my_id` at the same statement, but I can't seem to do so either.

I want a really fast and efficient way to do this.

```
select count(*) + 1, balance, my_id
from bank b
where b.balance > (select balance from bank where customer_number = 43543535);
```

---

```
select bank.*
from (select bank.*, rank() over (order by balance desc) as rnk
      from bank
     ) bank
where customer_number = 554113153538064391;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? [MySQL 8 added `rank`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/)

Comment: @Schwern Server version: 5.7.30

Comment: @Schwern I edited my answer but I get a syntax error

Comment: *I want to find what rank position* It is DENSE_RANK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the rank, then this query should be fine:

```
select count(*) + 1
from bank b
where b.balance > (select balance from bank where customer_number = 43543535);
```

For performance, you want an index on `bank(customer_number)` and `bank(balance)`.

EDIT:

For all information, use `JOIN`:

```
select count(*) + 1, bb.*
from bank b join
     (select balance from bank where customer_number = 43543535) bb
     on b.balance >= bb.balance;
```

MySQL should allow the `bb.*`, even though this is an aggregation query.  Formally, you should have `group by bb.customer_number`.

Comment: This query is fine if I just want the rank, but I want their rank, `my_id` and their `balance`